# I don't see the options menu in the fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using `bottom navigation`. I want to open a `dialog window` by selecting the `option menu` after switching to another fragment screen through the bottom menu.

But I don't see the `option menu`..

I wrote it by referring to other sample code, but I do not know the cause

***WorkoutListFragment.kt***

```
class WorkoutListFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_list, container,false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.record_item_add, menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val dialog = BodyPartDialogFragment()
        dialog.show(activity!!.supportFragmentManager, "BodyPartDialog")
        return true
    }
}
```

***ADDED***

```
val toolbar: Toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
(activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

***WorkouListFragment.xml***

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.WorkoutListFragment">
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppBarOverlay">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="LIST"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/black"
                app:titleMarginStart="30dp"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.PopupOverlay"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `onOptionsItemSelected` is called?

Comment: No, because `onOptionsItemSelected` is called only when the `option menu` is clicked, the `options menu` is not visible at all.

Comment: You're not sure? I would recommend finding that out first, then you can narrow down the cause.

Comment: hmm so difficult..

Comment: Difficult to find out?

Comment: Yes, I’m sorry, but I can’t guess.

Comment: I solved it. I don't know why, but the toolbar was the cause...

Should I use the toolbar to specify the options menu?

Comment: What do you mean by *specify the options menu*?

Comment: The options menu only appears on the App Bar. There are various different ways to include an App Bar. Including a Toolbar in your layout and setting it as the support action bar is the recommended way of doing it. https://developer.android.com/training/appbar

Comment: @HenryTwist I don't know exactly...

Comment: @Tenfour04 Do you mean the toolbar is for the action of the app bar?

Comment: I actually don't see the benefit of using the action bar approach although I would love to know if there are any actual benefits @Tenfour04 (aside from back compatibility)? You can use the toolbar as a standalone widget and inflate the options menu/handle clicks directly.

Comment: @HenryTwist The main advantage when helping newcomers is just that it matches the lessons in the official documentation so there's less to explain. In this case, OP is using the functions that work with the support action bar.

Comment: That's true, although I really think they should change the approach in the documentation, they're clearly trying to migrate away from the activity/fragment 'callback' style of programming, like with the new activity results API etc.

Comment: @ybybyb If you set the Toolbar as your support action bar, then the menu you inflate with `onCreateOptionsMenu` is automatically added to it.

Comment: @HenryTwist Does the meaning of standalone widget mean that it is better to use only Toolbar widgets without using AppbarLayout?

Comment: @Tenfour04 oh, yea thank you

Comment: No sorry @ybybyb that's not what I meant. There's a way to do this without every setting it as an action bar, but as has already been said, the documentation recommends the action bar approach so I would go with that. I doubt there is a technical difference. The `AppBarLayout` is to implement scrolling gestures, so has nothing to do with the toolbar itself.

Comment: @HenryTwist It's a bit difficult to understand, but I think I should just go over it.

The point is, isn't it that the app bar is composed of toolbars, not action bars?

Comment: The app bar is the *concept* of the bar at the top of the screen (sometimes called an action bar). `Toolbar` is a *widget* which acts as an app bar/action bar. The `AppBarLayout` is another *widget* that provides an implementation for scrolling gestures and animations.

Comment: @HenryTwist Then, isn't `AppbarLayout` absolutely necessary to implement `App Bar`?

Can i implement an `app bar` with only the `Toolbar`?

Comment: No not at all, it can just provide extra features, like scrolling gestures. The `Toolbar` is all you technically need.